# VLAN Through Switch Doesn't Work

Tags: switch, vlan

I have the following scenario:

I have a Cisco Aironet 1040 access point. I have it configured with two SSIDs, each going to a different VLAN. So:

```
SSID internal : VLAN 90
SSID guest    : VLAN 70
```

On the router side, I have a Cisco RV220W (with the radios now turned off) and have setup VLANs with like VLAN IDs.

```
VLAN 90    : 192.168.90.0/24
VLAN 70    : 192.168.70.0/24
```

As far as DHCP is concerned, each VLAN has a "DHCP Server" in the router's configuration:

[image]

So with the access point connected directly to the router, everything works great. I connect to the internal network, and I get a 192.168.90.x address, and the guest network gets a 70.xxx address.

Next I introduced a Cisco SG200-50 PoE switch between the router and the access point. The port is configured as a trunk port, so the VLAN tags should go right through the switch back to the router.

However, when something is connected to the access point, nothing works. It isn't able to get an IP address, and manually assigning one doesn't seem to let any traffic route.

Given that the access point works correctly when connected to the router directly, I believe the switch is misconfigured. What am I missing here? What can I use to better diagnose what the problem might be?

It's small business equipment, so CLI access is not available. Below are screenshots of the switch's config.

The access point is connected to GE2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there is any way I can improve this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Layer2 switches I have ever worked with needed to be aware of all the VLAN's it will carry. Your image suggests it only knows of Vlan 1.

Can't really help you how to add VLANs to this particular SOHO switch, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXnt4kY_fAw) claim to cover L3 routing between VLANs so it could be a good start, even though you don't seem to intend to perform routing in it.

A quick test could also be to utilize VLAN 1 on the AP, and you should be in contact with the DHCP server in that subnet.

Comment: Yes, in addition to this - I needed to join the ports that were involved into the VLANs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In general on the switch you will need to do 2, possibly 3 things:

1 Define the port to with the AP AND the port to which the routers connects BOTH as trunk.

2 Define vlan 70 and vlan 90 on the switch. It won't magically discover their existence.

3 Maybe (depends on exact model of switch) you also need to allow both VLAN's to be send over the trunk ports.